# Possibility that two students answer the same on a 10 question multiple choice test

Tags: probability

The assumption is that the answers are chosen at random by both students (these aren't real questions).
I tried `1/4^10` for one student and square it for two students `1/4^10 x 1/4^10`

Is that the right answer?

Comment: I’m afraid not. Pretend that one student’s answers are the answer key. What’s the probability that the other student gets a perfect score based on that key?

Comment: Multiple choice test: how many choices per question?

Comment: since I used 1/4 it is apparent that it is a 4 choice question.